# Sending device token in Apple push notification

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

The tutorials that I have come across for push notification manages the sending of device token along with the data that user sends for web service requests. My app too uses webservices but for my application, when a record is added to the website, it has to be notified on my app. So when and how do I send my device token from my iphone app? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending the device tokken to the server every time the user logs in. I'm making a http-request (on wich i add the device tokken) to check the password & email. If the entered data is ok, i save the tokken in the database.

Comment: So you are sending device token on user log in.. but without any user action how do i send the token?

Comment: I would send it in app deligate. Maybee you want to use asihttp to send it. Send it in the -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function

Comment: yep..using http request. I'll let you know after i try it out :)